# PostGIS, PostgreSQL and Solaris

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I need to install PostGIS on Solaris, but at the moment of installing I have this error:

> database=# create extension postgis; ERROR:  could not load library
>   "/opt/csw/lib/64/postgresql/93/rtpostgis-2.1.so": ld.so.1: postgres:
>   fatal: relocation error: file
>   /opt/csw/lib/64/postgresql/93/rtpostgis-2.1.so: symbol
>   GDALApproxTransform: referenced symbol not found

The installation steps I followed:

```
# pkgadd -d http://get.opencsw.org/now
# /opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -U
# /opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i postgresql93_server
# /opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i postgresql93_client
# /opt/csw/bin/pkgutil -y -i postgis
su - posrgres
$cd /opt/csw/bin/
$./initdb\-93 -D /opt/bads0001_data/datacsw/
$./pg_ctl\-93 -D /opt/bads0001_data/datacsw/ -l /opt/postgres/server.log -w start
```

Then I started postgres, created a database and created the extension:

```
Database = # create extension postgis;
```

Comment: Sounds like PostGIS was compiled with a different version of GDAL than what you have installed.  Any way for you to upgrade GDAL? perhaps a -i gdal